# Swagger Codegen :- Vendor Extensions are not accessible

Tags: swagger, mustache, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I am using the sample [Pet Store JSON file](https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json) to generate the spring-boot based project.
To add annotation such as @EnableEurekaClient in the generated code I am trying to use vendor extension in swagger file. Extensions name can be seen below as *x-enableEureka* in swagger defination.

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "This is a sample server Petstore server.  You can find out more about     Swagger at [http://swagger.io](http://swagger.io) or on [irc.freenode.net, #swagger](http://swagger.io/irc/).      For this sample, you can use the api key `special-key` to test the authorization     filters."
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: "Swagger Petstore"
  termsOfService: "http://swagger.io/terms/"
  x-enableEureka: true
```

I have modified the `controller.mustache` by adding below items. However, I am unable to access its value in generated Controller Class from either of the below statment.

```
{{vendorExtensions.x-enableEureka}} 
{{x-enableEureka}}
```

My intent is to use x-enableEureka as a condition.

```
{{^vendorExtensions.x-enableEureka}}
@EnableEurekaClient
{{/vendorExtensions.x-enableEureka}}
```

Similar way to access the vendor extension has been defined [here](https://arnoldgalovics.com/accessing-custom-attributes-in-swagger-codegen/). I am not sure why it's not working.

Can somebody please help me. I am not sure if I am placing the vendor extension at wrong place. I even tried to place that inside the Path  block as well.

**Swagger Codegen Version 2.4.15**

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `#` sign instead of `^`. The correct usage is

```
{{#vendorExtensions.x-enableEureka}}
@EnableEurekaClient
{{/vendorExtensions.x-enableEureka}}
```

Sorry for the late response.